# What is the best way to automatically send a failed network request when the internet connection is back on?

Tags: android, performance

Which libraries take care of this scenario by default? What is the best way to implement this if not using a library?

Comment: As per my Aspect you can maintain some State in DB for particular record. If that record upload successfully then change state with 1 and if you request for upload a record and if you failed for any reason then the state is same 0 means record could not uploaded in server(so try again after some time).

Comment: Yup thats certainly a good contender,but it would be reinveinting the wheel as its a common use case. Are there libraries which already take care of this?

Comment: I don't think so. There are many libraries but almost all worked with `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: Could you name a few of them?

Comment: It's `SyncIt` and many more search in _Google_.

Answer (score 0):

maintain one SYNC_FLAG in db...
if network connection is on then look for entries with SYNC_FLAG as 0 and resend them..
Once you get success alter table with SYNC_FLAG as 1.

Comment: You can enhance this with using a timestamp instead of a flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a Service to check when your internet connection is back on:

```
public class NetWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(networkInfo.isConnected()) {
             /* Internet is back on */
             /* Check if any requests need to be send */
        }
    }
}
```

This Service will detect whenever your Wifi connection becomes available. You should have a check to know if your request has failed due to internet connection, and then perform the request again inside the method (networkInfo.isConnected()).